# How to make a button be active one at a time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make buttons such that only one is active at a time. But I can't get it to work.

My HTML:

```html
<button class="js-toggle" onclick="toggle()">Gaming</button>
<button class="js-music-toggle" onclick="toggle2()">Music</button>
<button class="js-tech-toggle" onclick="toggle3()">Tech</button>
```

My JavaScript code:

```js
const btnElem = document.querySelector('.js-toggle')
const techBtn = document.querySelector('.js-tech-toggle')
const musicBtn= document.querySelector('.js-music-toggle')

function toggle() {
  if (!btnElem.classList.contains('is-toggled')) {
    btnElem.classList.add('is-toggled')
  } else {
    btnElem.classList.remove('is-toggled')
  }
}

function toggle2() {
  if (!musicBtn.classList.contains('is-toggled')) {
    musicBtn.classList.add('is-toggled')
  } else {
    musicBtn.classList.remove('is-toggled')
  }
}

function toggle3() {
  if (!techBtn.classList.contains('is-toggled')) {
    techBtn.classList.add('is-toggled')
  } else {
    techBtn.classList.remove('is-toggled')
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use radio buttons and style them to look like regular buttons.

Comment: What have you tried?
This code seems to toggle each button on and off, but there is no logic here that connects the buttons in any way shape or form.

Typically you would add a wrapper around the buttons that keeps the state of which button should be toggled

Comment: There is a lot of redundancy in that code. Isn't it possible to parameterise it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
function toggle(btnElem) {
    if (!btnElem.classList.contains('is-toggled')) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".is-toggled").forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('is-toggled'));
      btnElem.classList.add('is-toggled');
      return;
    } 
    btnElem.classList.remove('is-toggled')
}
```

```css
.is-toggled {
  color:red;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<button class="js-toggle" onclick="toggle(this)">Gaming</button>
<button class="js-music-toggle" onclick="toggle(this)">Music</button>
<button class="js-tech-toggle" onclick="toggle(this)">Tech</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please use this code:

Code:

```js
const buttonContainer = document.querySelector('.button-container')
const buttons = buttonContainer.querySelectorAll('button')

buttonContainer.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    buttons.forEach(button => {
      if (button !== e.target) {
        button.classList.remove('is-toggled')
      }
    })
    e.target.classList.toggle('is-toggled')
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="js-toggle">Gaming</button>
  <button class="js-music-toggle">Music</button>
  <button class="js-tech-toggle">Tech</button>
</div>
```

Comment: 2 pointers. 1. Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can put your code and make it a snippet. 2. Please add explanation. What did you change, why did you change, how did it solve the issue OP's code had

Comment: Lack of indentation in JS is difficult to read. Please take the time to properly format.